# Sending email to server

Tags: php, html, security, email, smtp

I'm going to be having users email something to the server, then the email will be used for something on the website.

Is the way I'm going to do it a suitable solution?

I plan on sending the users a randomly generated secret key that they email it to, something like `89d8fhg78dfh78h@website.com`. Then the server handles the incoming data.

Would this be a secure way to do so? Or is there an easier and better way? Also if it is a good way, how would I handle the secret key?

Like how would I route the emails to the certain user if my solution is suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure if I'm clear with what you're trying to do here. For what you suggest, the easiest way to handle it would be to assign that specific e-mail to a user in the process of sending it. You'd then check upon incoming e-mail whether or not that e-mail belongs to anyone, and if it does, you'd process it.

It'd be easier to provide alternatives if you explained what you were actually doing. Is this some knd of verification method? Is there a reason this cannot be handled on-site with real-time validation?

Comment: Well it could he handled on the site, but this is just an alternative method. For the email, what if the email becomes compromised, anyone would be able to send the stuff to the user then....

Comment: There's no way to avoid that the first time around with your method - but once the user has e-mailed you on the randomized e-mail the first time around, you could store his e-mail and check that any incoming e-mails are from that user. This will not help you if a malevolent person spoofs his e-mail however, but there's no way for you to know that.

Comment: So basically the best way is handling on site?

Comment: That would definately be my call. That way you can directly verify whatever you need verified real-time with the user ON your site.

Comment: @user302975 Glad to help! Sorry I couldn't offer a better solution according to what you initially requested, but I do believe this to be a more viable and safe solution.